# How to add a location label (like starring) to Google Maps (website), like in the 2015 updated Android app?

Tags: google-maps

At some point in 2015 I believe Google Maps on Android added the ability to add a label to any location from the vertical `...` menu when a location is selected. This label is saved in your account - similar to Starring locations (I think it replaces starring locations, I don't seem to be able to star locations in the app any more).

**I can't find the equivalent feature in the Google Maps website.**

How do I add this new type of label which is saved to my account?

I've tried searching but I just get results for old-google-maps APIs, map maker tools, embedded maps and similar. I'm looking for plain regular labels.

---

Also, possibly related, "Labels" that I created on my phone app don't seem to show up while I'm logged in as the same user on the website. All the same starred locations show up - but not labels (and it doesn't seem to still be possible to add starred locations on the Android app). I'm confused as to whether this is a feature where the website version failed to keep up with the apps, or whether I need to enable something, or some other reason for the mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, Google is not currently sharing all that data between the Android Maps app and the Google Maps website. I thought perhaps it would show under "[My Maps](http://mymaps.google.com)", but no such luck.

However, if you *search* in the Google Maps website for a label that you've created, it will get found. It doesn't otherwise show your label, however, nor do I see a way to create labels from the Maps website.

I also found this from [Gizmodo](http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/create-custom-names-for-your-favorite-places-on-google-1719908604)

> The feature doesn’t look quite finished yet—your changes don’t appear on the web...

so perhaps it's not yet fully baked. Maybe in a month or two this can be re-visited.

Comment: Interesting, yes I can find my labels by searching but can only create them or see them on the map through the app. Sounds like a classic example of two Google departments not talking to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't see a feature for labelling locations, you can "star" a location to save it in web Google Maps and Android Google Maps, and Maps quickly shares that information between the web and Android.

To star a location on web Google Maps:

1. Click a red circle  location marker to open its listing **or** click a point on the map (you might have to click once to deselect a previous item then click again to select a point) then click the mini-listing near the bottom of the map to open its listing.
2. Click the ★ (star) "Save" icon.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works when the specific location exists as a named location that Google Maps already recognises. For example, if I want to mark a point on a long road, or a location of a business Google doesn't already know about, when I click the point on the map all I get is the nearest landmark, then if I select that and press the star button, Google puts the star at some random central point relative to the arbitrary landmark, instead of the specific spot I chose.

Comment: Ah, clicking the map gets a mini-listing at any location (showing coordinates) *but* clicking that mini-listing snaps to the nearest point-of-interest, and that's all you can star/save. **Suggestion:** Use the "Send Feedback" link at the bottom to report this. Include examples that show why this really matters, e.g. to save graffiti locations to clean up.